# pandas: calculate the average time and standard deviation of unique values of column

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

assuming I have a list of processes A,B,C,D.... with times

```
Process time
A        3
A        4
B        5
C        6
B        7
A        4
A        5
B        2
C        3

import pandas as pd
mydf = pd.DataFrame(columns=['process','time'],
 data={'process':list('ABCABCABCDAABB'),'time':[2,3,4,5,6,4,5,6,4,5,6,2,3,4]})
```

What I want to extract is a Dataframe with only one entry per process per row and two columns, the average time and the standard deviation.

I solved the problem as follows

```
processes=mydf.process.unique()
dfstats = pd.DataFrame(columns=['P','average','std'])

for process in processes:
    mask = mydf.process == process
    average,std = mydf.loc[mask,['time']]['time'].mean(),mydf.loc[mask,['time']]['time'].std()
    dfstats.loc[len(dfstats)] =[process,average,std]
```

I have the feeling that there should be a straight way to do this. my solution is too verbose, too long, and probably too slow (I am dealing with a couple of million rows)

any other more pythonic-pandonic solution?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are finding the statistics of each group.  This can be done via `groupby` and `agg`:

```
df.groupby("process").agg(["mean", "std"])
```

output:

```
        mean       std
process
A        4.0  1.870829
B        4.4  1.516575
C        4.0  0.000000
D        5.0       NaN
```

Comment: yeah, definitely useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `NamedAgg` on `Series.Groupby`

```
mydf.groupby('process')['time'].agg(average='mean', std='std').reset_index()

Out[148]:
  process  average       std
0       A      4.0  1.870829
1       B      4.4  1.516575
2       C      4.0  0.000000
3       D      5.0       NaN
```